# Solve equation in $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$ without brute-force

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all solutions to $x^3 = 7$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$ using theory and not brute-force. I dont know how to proceed, I used brute-forced but dont know what kind of theory to use otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

[You know](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) that every $a \not\equiv 0 \pmod{13}$  satisfies $a^{12} \equiv 1 \pmod{13}$. So if there is $x$ such that $x^{3} \equiv 7 \pmod{13}$, then $$1 \equiv x^{12}\equiv (x^{3})^{4} \equiv 7^4 \pmod{13}.$$

But $$7^{4} \equiv (49)^{2} \equiv (-3)^{2} \equiv 9 \pmod{13}.$$

Comment: Great answer. I noticed it doesnt yield for any prime, what if $p=19$? I didnt know the equation didnt have solutions, I want a method to find solutions.

Comment: @Bob, AFAIK, even for finding square roots there is no deterministic, polynomial time algorithm. But the probabilistic one works well, see en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\,{\rm mod}\ 13\!:\ x\not\equiv 0\,\overset{\rm Fermat}\Rightarrow\,(x^6)^2\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, x^6\equiv \pm1,\,$ but $\,x^3\equiv 7\,\Rightarrow\,x^6\equiv 7^2\equiv 10\ne\pm 1$